# Exception not bubbling up from Task (TPL)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Why are exceptions not being caught in the `catch (AggregateException aEx)` block of this code?

```
class Program
    {
        private static int _sum = 0;
        private static object _sumLock = new object();
        public static int Sum
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_sumLock)
                {
                    return _sum;
                }            
            }
            set
            {
                lock (_sumLock)
                {
                    _sum = value;
                }          
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var taskList = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => throw new Exception()));
                }
                else
                {
                    taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => Sum++));
                }               
            }

            try
            {
                //var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var completionTask = Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray()).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Sum {Sum}"));
                completionTask.Wait(100);
            }
            catch (AggregateException aEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aEx.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW I know this isn't the point of the question, but that Sum++ isn't thread-safe - the read is synchronized and the write is synchronized, but you could get lost updates between the two. Your best bet here would be either to synchronize *over the ++*, or to use an interlocked increment

Comment: To bubble up exceptions you need to wait/await the task with exception, but only task you are waiting in the code created by `ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Sum {Sum}"))` and not throw exception.

Comment: _"Why are exceptions not being caught"_ -- because that's how `Task` works. You called `ContinueWith()`, and are waiting for _that_ task, not the one that throws the exception. If you want the waited-for task to throw an exception, you either need to fix your continuation task to do so, or wait on the original. See marked duplicates for a couple of the many essentially-identical questions here on Stack Overflow.